# Log BackgroundWorker activity in a different class from the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am using BackgroundWorker in some class (let's say "class A").

Now, from my MainWindow I call a function in this class that uses this BW.

How can I put some text in a TextBox that belongs to the MainWindow?

Comment: Share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting an exception because you're updating the textbox from another thread? I'd also like to add that using async/await is probably a better idea than a background worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dispatcher to invoke a an action to perform of the main thread. For more information read msdn article [Building Responsive UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)
For example

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                           new Action(() => this.TextBoxToUpdate.Text= "Updated"));
```